# My most important factor column has too many levels and I cant pull out the important information

Tags: r, machine-learning, text-mining

I have completed a Boruta algorithm on a data set to determine which variables are the most impactful on the target variable.  The goal is to determine which variables have the most impact on homes in a specific neighborhood.  After learning that the Appliances in my dataset is a very important factor, I ran into the issue of the target column being over run with information.  I can not decipher what items lead to a higher price and which ones lead to a lower price. I tried to run a regression on the factors but because each item is over run with information I am not able to pull anything useful from the regression.  I've also tried to change the factors into characters and mine them as text with no luck. Might anyone know a good method or algorithm that can be used to display the key words that have the impact on the target variable.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUoym.png)

Comment: The data is miss leading.  Most of the categories only 1 or at most few cases and there are 36 homes with no appliances.  I find this hard to believe and unreliable.  I question the data associated with all of the other cases as well. I suggest trying to follow J_H advice.  But you are going to lose a lot of information with the 36 with no information.

Answer (score 0):

You described `appliances` as "a feature".

Here are some example values:

```
Stove
Refrigerator
Stove,Refrigerator
Stove,Refrigerator,Dishwasher
Central Air Conditioner
```

That is not a single feature!
You have several booleans conflated
into one column there.
Break out an indicator feature column
for `Dishwasher` and for all the rest.
Then let Boruta determine which subset
of the indicators are informative.